# AngularJs Page load error

Tags: angularjs, syntax

I am running an angularjs web page. Its working fine everytime when I refreshes the web page, but all of a sudden it has started throwing the error

```
angular.min.js:15 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token / in JSON at position 2
```

I am not understanding why suddenly the page is throwing this error which was working fine previously.

Any help is appreciated!!!

Thanks

Comment: code please. are you calling any api which returns a JSON response ? or do you have a variable to which you have assigned an object ?

Comment: No , I am not calling any API

Comment: I just configured a request interceptor in config function

Comment: can you comment that interceptor out and check if you are still getting this error or not.

Comment: This error is appearing only in chrome not in any other browser